# Django - pre-save VS post-save VS view save

Tags: python, django, signals

I want to perform some action (sending email) after updating an (already existing) object.
In order to do it I need to compare values of the object before and after saving and only if something specific has changed - do that action. From reading other related question I understood that I can only do it in pre-save signal, since I can't get the old version inside 'post-save', but - what if there will be some issue with saving and the item will not be saved? I don't want to perform the action in that case. So I thought about implementing it somehow by overriding the view save, but I'm not sure that's the correct way to do it. What do you think?
This is implementing in pre-save:

```
@staticmethod
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Item)
# check if there is change that requires sending email notification.
def send_email_notification_if_needed(sender, instance, raw, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        # if item just created - don't do anything
        pre_save_item_obj = sender.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
    except sender.DoesNotExist:
        pass  # Object is new, so field hasn't technically changed
    else:
        # check if state changed to Void 
        if pre_save_item_obj.state_id != VOID and instance.state_id == VOID:
            content = {"item_name": instance.title, "item_description": instance.description}

            EmailNotificationService().send_email("item_update"
                                                  ["myemail@gmail.com"], str(instance.container.id) +
                                                 str(instance.id) + " changed to Void",
                                                  content)
```

Comment: what do you mean by this line `what if there will be some issue with saving and the item will not be saved` If there is no exception raised in your pre save handler then I don't think there is possibility of something going wrong

Comment: @ArpitSolanki There are plenty of possibilities where the actual saving can go wrong! Lucky you, if you have never had an `IntegrityError` from your db, e.g. for violating unique constraints or the like?

Comment: IntegrityError is something your own error. If you take good counter measures then It can be easily avoided. @schwobaseggl

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with overriding the model's `save` method. After all, this is where you have all the information that you need:

```
class X(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pre_obj = X.objects.filter(pk=self.pk).first()
        super(X, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        # no exception from save
        if pre_obj and pre_obj.state_id != VOID and self.state_id == VOID:
            # send mail
```